# How secure is the networking built into AWS Mobile SDK for iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to have access to dynamodb tables for a mobile app through the Mobile SDK. Mainly, I'd like to access public encryption keys stored in a dynamodb table, and perhaps even send encrypted personnal information data (dob, credit card numbers, etc) through the mobile sdk directly into Dynamodb via the SDK.

Can anyone give me insights as to how secure the connections might be with the mobile SDKs, and if this is a use case that we devs can bank on when using the AWS Mobile SDK? I'm mainly looking to find out if the SDK uses TLS or HTTPS to handle POST/PUT type calls to dynamodb.

Any guidance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Mobile SDK for Android uses HTTPS by default unless otherwise specified.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.java#L91